# Date differences with tuples representing dates

Tags: python, date, tuples

Using Python3, I have tuples representing dates, e.g. (2008, 11, 10).
I would like to manipulate these as dates, e.g to find date differences (subtractions) between 2 such tuples with result in days.
I have looked here for ways to convert tuples into dates but have had no success.

(I can convert them into strings and manipulate those, using things like strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") but that seems a long way around)

The examples I see start with literals:

```
var = datetime.date(2008, 11, 10)
```

or from system values:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
```

but I need to start with:

```
myvariable = (2008, 11, 10)     # the value that it has already
var = datetime.date(myvariable)
```

which gives:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

I realise that this is a newbie question. I just need a little help.

Comment: Thanks @zipa. Works. Easy when you know it but I doubt if I would have found it without help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [unpack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) it:

```
myvariable = (2008, 11, 10)
var = datetime.date(*myvariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct syntax should be datetime.date(year, month, day)

```
myvariable = (2008, 11, 10)
var = datetime.date(myvariable[0],myvariable[1],myvariable[2])
```

now var has datetime object. For Further methods you can refer this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)